# How to fix "Keyword not supported" error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, jdbc, ubuntu-16.04

I'm developing a webapi using .Net Core 2.0, Microsoft SqlServer and EntityFramework on Ubuntu 16.04.  The IDE is JetBrains Rider and I can attach a SQLServer database to the IDE's Database Window using a connection string like this:

`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=TestDb;User=`....

However when trying to update the database from the terminal using

`"dotnet ef database update -s ../MyWeb/"`

I get the following error:

> Keyword not supported: 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database'.

I spent hours googling and trying to fix this but so far no luck.  Is there anything I'm missing, like a reference to the jdbc driver or something like that?

Comment: I think you should use 'databaseName' instead of 'database' according to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url

Comment: Are you really using JDBC? Shouldn't you be using a normal SQL Server connection string?

Comment: The combination of C#, JDBC and entity-framework cannot work. JDBC is for Java (JetBrains Rider is written in Java!), not .NET/C#. So if you are programming in C#, then you must use a C# SQL Server connection string, not a Java connection string.

Comment: I assumed (wrongly), that the connectionstring given by Rider is the one to use (In the same way as in Windows Visual Studio), but as pointed out by David and Mark, this is not possible.  However, in fairness I did try out the same connection strings I had working in Windows, but they failed, too.  Today, with a fresh mind, I found the answer and what I missed.

Comment: Consider self-answering your question with your solution, it may help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer today with a fresh mind. Under Windows I connected using "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=..." but under Ubuntu1604 I only got it to work with the following connectionstring:

> "Server=tcp:localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;j ..."

Comment: localdb and named instances are not currently supported on Linux.